# How to remove ? (question mark) from url when it is not followed by any parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, url, query-string

I have a form that sends a get request to the server. the input parameters are sent to the server in QueryString.

This is my form:

```
<form action="host-name/Home/Browse"  onsubmit="removeEmptyParameters()">
    <input type="text" name="Term" /> 
    <input type="text" name="Address" /> 
    <input type="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

Before submitting the form, the following JavaScript method is executed to remove the empty input parameters from the form:

```
function removeEmptyParameters() {
    // set the name attribute = "" for empty inputs, so they won't be posted to server
    $('form').find('input').each(function () {
        if (this.value === "") {
            $(this).attr('name', '');
        }
    });
}
```

So if user enters some input, the request would be:

*ulr: host-name/Home/Browse?Term=some-term&Address=some-address*

If all the inputs are empty, the following url is sent to server:

*ulr: host-name/Home/Browse?*

This works fine, but I would like to remove `?` from url, so it would be clean. Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the String.prototype.slice() method to achieve this. If the last character of your url is '?', you can remove it from the url string.

```js
let url = "www.someurl.com?";
let length = url.length;
if(url.charAt(length-1)==='?')
url=url.slice(0,length-1);
console.log(url);
```

Please visit the following MDN link for more details on slice():
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/slice

I am not sure if this is the best solution, but you can try to use window.location.href to redirect incase the parameters are empty. In that way, it would be possible to keep the url clean.

Comment: Thanks, but how to get the url??

Comment: I am not sure if this is the best solution, but you can try to use *window.location.href* to redirect incase the parameters are empty. In that way, it would be possible to keep the url clean.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion, I ended up doing what you suggested and redirected to new location instead of submitting the form. If you include your suggestion in your answer I would mark it as accepted answer.

Comment: @HoomanBahreini I am glad the solution worked out for you! I have included it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could rewrite your code something like this.

With this approach, your browser URL doesn't change dynamically based on the form values and your URL looks clean.

And you can also make use of the jquery library(since your code is already written using jquery) to submit the form using ajax where you can dynamically modify the form URL based on the input data. This way you have more control.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
    integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo=" crossorigin="anonymous">
    </script>

  <head>

  <body>
    <!-- Replace with your hostname instead of https://eniuu7vo8sak.x.pipedream.net -->
    <form method="GET" onsubmit="return handleSubmit('https://eniuu7vo8sak.x.pipedream.net/Home/Browse')">
      <input type="text" name="Term" />
      <input type="text" name="Address" />
      <input type="submit" value="submit">
    </form>

    <script>

      function handleSubmit(url) {
        removeEmptyParameters();
        const formData = $('form').serialize();
        console.log(formData);
        // Only adds the question mark to the url only if there are some input data.
        if (formData) {
          url = `${url}?${formData}`;
        }
        $.get(url);
        return false;
      }

      function removeEmptyParameters() {
        // set the name attribute = "" for empty inputs, so they won't be posted to server
        $('form').find('input').each(function () {
          if (this.value === "") {
            $(this).attr('name', '');
          }
        });
      }            
    </script>

  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: Kindly include an explanation of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes.

Comment: @Android Thank you for your suggestion. And I have edited the post to include some comments.

Answer (score 0):

Put this script on your landing page. The question mark will be visible for few milliseconds, but in most cases nobody will notice.
There will be no page reload because you deal with `window.history`.

```
if( document.addEventListener ) {
    if( document.readyState === "complete"
            || (document.readyState !== "loading" && !document.documentElement.doScroll) 
    ) {
        fixUrl();
    }
    else {
        document.addEventListener(
            "DOMContentLoaded", 
            function() { fixUrl(); },
            { "once" : true }
        );
    }
}

function fixUrl() {
    let url = window.location.href;
    if( url.endsWith("?") ) { url = url.substring( 0, url.length-1 ); }
    window.history.pushState( {"page":"TheSamePage"}, "TheSamePage", url );
}
```